# why new Date() function gives different output in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, date, time

I am passing this new Date into both Firefox and Chrome console (same computer, and time zone) and I am getting mixed results.So confusing...
In chrome
new Date();
//Wed Dec 09 2015 18:06:55 GMT+0530 (IST)

In firefox
new Date();
//Date 2015-12-09T12:36:34.410Z

Answer (score 8):

Your confusion is caused by different time-zones displaying.

Your Chrome gives you the time in UTC+0, while Firefox gives you the time in GMT+0530.

You can specify you want both to always be UTC by writing

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.toISOString() // will give you a date in the format you see by Chrome
```

Comment: Nice one. I completely misread the question. :-) It's worth noting that the `Date` object has the same value, the difference here is purely how it's being *output* when turned into a string.

Comment: Date instances do not have a UTC method. What you might have intended is [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) (which is sepcified as ISO 8601 long format in UTC) or [*toUTCString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring), which is implementation dependent but always uses UTC for values.

Comment: @RobG You are correct, I've checked it before posting but seems like a specific library might've added that to the date prototype.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the result of [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring), which is **entirely** implementation dependent. So you may well see a different string in every client you test.

You can use [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) to get an ISO 8601 format string that is UTC. There is a [*polyfill on MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Polyfill).

```js
document.write(new Date().toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not like the '-' in the string

Replace all occurrences of - with / using a regular expression and then convert the string to Date object.

```
var str = '01-25-2019 10:28:15 AM';

str = str.replace(/-/g,'/');  //replaces all occurances of "-" 
with "/"

var dateobject = new Date(date_string);

alert(dateobject.toDateString());
```